# Packet loss in CAN

Tags: signal-integrity, can

How susceptible is a CAN bus to packet loss, and what are the sources of packet loss in CAN?

I realize the answer may depend heavily on the application, so here are some details:

- bus length: about 1 m.
- bus utilization: potentially high.
- # of nodes: 5-20.

The bus is for use in arm prostheses. I'm wondering what the need is for an explicit sequence number/ack system for periodic communication of sensor data.

If someone knows something about this, or knows of a document discussing this in some detail, that would be very useful.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is too vague to really answer.  However, CAN is quite robust, at least if you use the common differential bus system with twisted pair and a 120 Ohm terminator at each end.  You should be able to run at the full 1 MHz bit rate without issue.  Lots of traffic may delay packets, but they shouldn't be lost due to this unless the total bus bandwidth is insufficient.

Comment: CAN can also be run at different speeds, and as with most communication you'd expect a greater sensitivity to errors at higher speeds. You may find that you can get away with a relatively low speed for your application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Packets are only lost if an error occurs, so the answer is very much an "it depends on the noise levels" :)  Only one node "owns" the bus at any time and all nodes agree on who that should be (by the end of the arbitration phase).  At the end of the message there will be an acknowledgement from every node which received the message correctly and potentially a negative acknowledgement from any node which received it incorrectly.  If that NAK is present, all nodes will invalidate the message and await a retry.

However, the error detection and recovery parts of CAN are only meant as a solution to random errors.  In a production system, I'd be very wary of any bus which showed any error-frames at all during "normal operation".

Another thing which might be considered "packet-loss" is a regular low-priority packet, which may not be able to arbitrate its way onto the bus often enough.  And if your CAN controller is FIFO-based (rather than true message-objects, each of which can arbitrate for priority internally), it may hold up higher-priority messages.  Simulations of the system can help you assess how often that might occur.

In my (automotive) experience, sequence numbers are often used as a check against the software going berserk and simply transmitting the same frame over and over again.  Any ACK/RETRY is left to the lower-protocol layers.

---

I have seen systems with a very (very!) electrically-noisy CAN bus showing several error-frames **per second(!)**... it worked, but had very occasional sequences of errors which causes one of the ECUs to go off the bus. Not recommended.

Another example of the error tolerance of CAN was a system which (in very early development) required a UART - the only pin available was the CAN enable pin.  Even with the bus driver being turned on and off (by the UART at 115200 bps), the messages still got through.  Again with a high rate of error-frames on the bus, but the retries got there in the end!  And again, not recommended!

Comment: Thanks, it's always nice to hear from someone with experience. Just to clarify, in what cases will a device ACK/NAK/neither? If a frame is corrupted, will devices that are listening calculate and check the CRC and NAK a frame with errors?

Answer (score 4):

CAN is quite robust provided the controllers that are hooked can handle errors gracefully.

1. Simplifying the communication would help a lot. Layers might make you to spend a lot of 
   time to process the data. If your mail boxes are limited, it may be overwritten. It is a 
   a good idea to run those tasks on the interrupt service routine.
2. Use remote frames instead of periodic messages that could hog the bus.
3. If a node goes power down, make sure when it powers up, it is initialized correctly.
4. Termination should be always available.
5. When a node BUSOFF, it should not retry till a reasonable amount of time say 5 seconds
   or you cycle power
6. EMC might be good if you are sending periodic junk, but it is not good for higher IDs to
   win the arbitration.

Corolla has 27 boxes on the CAN bus and you would not see even a single error frame for years.